# Windows 11 get old sound flyout

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

In Windows 11 there's a new sound-flyout when you change the volume with the `F3/4`-Keys. It always covers exactly the spot where you can pause and play the music on spotify. Is there any way to either remove this or revert to the Windows 10 version?

[image: The new soundbar]

Comment: 1)are you using the Spotify app or website? 2)from searching online this might be specific to a web browser your using, are you using chrome? https://www.technipages.com/windows-10-disable-volume-overlay

Comment: @gregg These are instructions for windows 10 not 11. I also didn't mention that I want my media keys to be disabled. It's just the sound indicator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a third-party product to gain more control over the
Volume Bar.

The free and open-source
[ModernFlyouts](https://github.com/ModernFlyouts-Community/ModernFlyouts)
seems like it would solve your problem, as
its volume bar is movable and adjustable in many ways.

For a demonstration, see the YouTube video
[How to get Modern Flyouts in Windows 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L56bFRAiBtY).

To hide the volume bar, leaving only the one of Modern Flyouts,
you may use the free
[HideVolumeOSD](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/HideVolumeOSD.shtml).

Comment: Well this would be a good alternative, but on Windows 11 I get the system flyout AND the one from this program so it doesn't really replace it. Is there a way to disable the system flyout as well?

Comment: Try [HideVolumeOSD](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/HideVolumeOSD.shtml).

Comment: Another option: https://github.com/Jax-Core/YourFlyouts